# PDO prepared query error: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm converting some unprepared PDO queries written by someone else to prepared PDO queries. All of the undefined variables and POSTed variables are in fact carried through in this routine; I'm omitting their definitions for brevity's sake. The proof is in the pudding, for the existing, non-prepared query, provided here, works:

```
$query = sprintf('INSERT INTO galleries (title, description, meta_description, published) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", %d)', addslashes($_POST['gallery_name']), addslashes($_POST['gallery_description']), addslashes($_POST['gallery_meta_description']), intval($published));
$connection->query($query);
```

However, my conversion of this code to a fully prepared query, here, does not:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO galleries (title, description, meta_description, published) VALUES (":title", ":description", ":meta_description", :published)';

$PdoStatementObject = $connection->prepare($query);

$title = addslashes($_POST['gallery_name']);
$description = addslashes($_POST['gallery_description']);
$meta_description = addslashes($_POST['gallery_meta_description']);
$published_int = intval($published);

$PdoStatementObject->bindValue(":title", $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$PdoStatementObject->bindValue(":description", $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$PdoStatementObject->bindValue(":meta_description", $meta_description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$PdoStatementObject->bindValue(":published", $published_int, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$PdoStatementObject->execute();
```

The error message generated is:

```
PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

What am I doing wrong? It looks to me as though every parameter is accounted for; what is causing the interpreter to claim that there's a token count mismatch?

Comment: placeholders on the prepared statement doesn't need quotations, and remove that superfluous addslashes

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of double quotes in place holder

```
(":title", ":description", ":meta_description", :published)
```

to

```
(:title, :description, :meta_description, :published)
```

Check the document http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: For the sake of completeness it may be worth adding that, with the quotation marks, the command attempts to insert the literal strings `":title"` etc (or, if the [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) SQL mode is enabled, the values of schema objects identified by those names—which almost certainly don't exist).